# How to create dynamic organizational chart from active directory data?

Tags: active-directory, visio

I want to create dynamic organizational chart from active directory. How can I do it? Is it possible to be done by Microsoft Visio? I want the employees in the organizational chart to be automatically updated based on the data in active directory.

Answer (score 0):

Using Microsoft Visio, you can update the employees' data, but you cannot update the structure automatically. Say, if A changes phone number from 000 to 111 then this change can be reflected automatically. But if A was a boss of B and now B became boss of A, or say A was in department XX managed by X, and now he moved to department YY managed by Y, that change cannot be reflected automatically. In other words, the hierarchy changes cannot be reflected automatically.

Comment: Can it be reflected using fresh all button? And do you any other application that does it automatically?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about applications that can build and refresh the org chart from active directory completely automatically. Visio "refresh" button you mention can refresh item data (such as phone number) when the diagram is properly bound to the data source.